# Is the group $S^1:=\{z\in \mathbb C :|z|=1\}$ isomorphic with $S^1\times S^1$ ?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, infinite-groups

Is the group $S^1:=\{z\in \mathbb C :|z|=1\}$ isomorphic with $S^1\times S^1$ ?

I know that $\mathbb C^* \cong S^1 \cong \mathbb R/\mathbb Z \cong \mathbb C^*/\mathbb R^+$ , but I cannot make any headway towards the original problem . Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider where you have to send the elements $(i, 0)$ and $(0,i)$ and other elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $n$ elements which satisfies $x^{n}=1$ in $S^{1}$ ($n$-th root of unities), but $n^{2}$ elements in $S^{1}\times S^{1}$ ($(\zeta_{n}^i, \zeta_{n}^j)$ for $1\leq i, j\leq n$).

Comment: that's not quite true ... $S^1$ has only $2$ elements of order $3$ and only $2$ elements of order $4$ .... but yeah that suffices as $S^1\times S^1$ has at least $4$ elements of order $3$

Comment: @SaunDev I'm confused. Thanks.

Comment: yes now it is okay ... of course there are $n$ complex numbers satisfying $x^n=1$ but not every one of them need be of order $n$ ... for example $1,-1$ satisfy $x^4=1$ but $1$ is identity itself and $-1$ has order $2$